# Regex split and replace

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to replace a word that starts with `%`.

For example `Welcome to home | %brand %productName`

hoping to split on words begining with `%` which would give me `{ brand, productName }`.

My regex is less than average so would appreciate help with this.

Comment: It would be easier if you used %brand% %productName%

Comment: Are you trying to get an array containing just "brand" and "productName" or are you trying to replace these words, if so what are you trying to replace them with?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as acceted if you got the solution you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with string.split approach, mind you, but here's a regex approach:

```
string input = @"Welcome to home | %brand %productName";
            string pattern = @"%\S+";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
            string result = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
            {
                result += "match " + i + ",value:" + matches[i].Value + "\n";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: thanks this was what I was looking for. need to brush up on my regex. I did previously use the string.split approach but was looking for a less cumbersome method. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Following code might help you :

```
string[] splits = "Welcome to home | %brand %productName".Split(' ');
List<string> lstdata = new List<string>();
for(i=0;i<splits.length;i++)
{
   if(splits[i].StartsWith("%"))
     lstdata.Add(splits[i].Replace('%',''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=%)\w+
```

This looks for any combination of word characters immediately preceded by a percent symbol.

Now, if you're doing search and replace on these matches, you'll probably want to remove the % sign as well, so you'd need to remove the lookbehind group and just have this:

```
%\w+
```

But in doing so, your replacement code would need to trim off the % sign from each match to get the word by itself.

Comment: You can use `%(\w+)` to match the group and replace whatever is needed.